# Measuring the product is the same as first measuring with one matrix then with the other

Tags: measurement

I want to show that if one measures $M_1$ on $|\psi\rangle$ then measures $M_2$ on the resulting state and then the associated probability space will be the same as the one for measuring the product $M_2 M_1$ on that pure state $|\psi\rangle$ (also assuming that the $M_i$ are Hermitian and commute). So in our first measurement procedure, we have two measurement operators, the first one yields,

$$p(1)=\langle \psi|M_1^\dagger M_1|\psi\rangle\tag{1}$$

and the resulting state is,

$$\frac{M_1|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi|M_1^\dagger M_1|\psi\rangle}}.\tag{2}$$

If we then measure it using $M_2$ then we get,

$$p(2)=\left\langle\frac{M_1|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi|M_1^\dagger M_1|\psi\rangle}} \bigg| M_2^\dagger M_2 \bigg| \frac{M_1|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi|M_1^\dagger M_1|\psi\rangle}}\right\rangle.\tag{3}$$

With $M_2M_1$ we get,

$$p(1)=\langle\psi|(M_2M_1)^\dagger M_2M_1|\psi\rangle.$$

However, we only have one measurement operator here being $M_2M_1$, so how can the probability spaces be the same?

Comment: Do you have a copy of Nielsen & Chuang? This, if I understand your question correctly, is exactly the content of exercise 2.57. [Here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://github.com/goropikari/SolutionForQuantumComputationAndQuantumInformation/raw/master/solnQCQI.pdf) (PDF alert) you can find the solutions (see page 22) ~ this is a rendered version of [this](https://github.com/goropikari/SolutionQCQINielsenChuang) github repo.

Comment: Are your $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ measurement *observables* or measurement *operators*?

Comment: @JSdJ They're measurement operators.

Comment: Your question is still a bit ambiguous to me; are $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ operators from the same of from different measurements? Remember - a _quantum measurement_ in its most general form is a set of operators $\{M_{m}\}$, where the outcome $m$ is associated to operator $M_{m}$ and occurs with probability $p(m) = \langle \psi | M_{m}^{\dagger}M_{m} | \psi \rangle$. If they are operators from different measurements (a _cascaded_ measurement), @ryanhill1 has shown that your identity holds. If they are operators from the _same_ measurement, your identity does not hold (in general).

Comment: $M_1$ and $M_2$ can be observables only, because it is stated in the question "$M_i$ are Hermitian and commute". It does not make sense for measurement operators. And then OP writes formulas for measurement operators, evidently not understating what he is doing. The question as it is does not make sense to me.

Comment: A PVM has Hermitian operators (as they are projectors), and they all commute (as they're orthogonal). But, then the question becomes trivial, because no state is in an eigenspace of both operators.

Comment: **Close voters: What's the problem? I see that JSdJ has some questions, but can we please give the user some time to answer those concerns? The user is brand new to this site, and we don't want their first experience to be a closed question. Furthermore: this quesiton already has two answers! The question was only asked yesterday.**

Comment: @kludg Why $A,B$ being Hermitian and commuting implies that measuring $AB$ on $|\psi\rangle$ does not yield a measurement operator?

Comment: @kludg Why are you being so rude? If I don't understand something then please clarify it or give some references. And yes I know that I have a misunderstanding here, and it's exactly the reason why this question has been bugging me for so long, and if you can help resolve that misunderstanding then it would do a great of help to me.

Comment: @kludg Why do you think the answer of Ryan is unsuitable? It seems you're not familiar with the definitions used in Nielsen which might be different from other sources.

Comment: @kludg How is it nonsense? It's literally in the book by Nielsen. I think you're just being closed minded by not admitting your lack of knowledge about the way things are formulated and defined Nielsen and you project ignorance on others.

Comment: Dude I hate this website, I'm outta here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of "multiplying the outcomes" the probability spaces are not equivalent. However, looking simply at cascading measurements versus single measurements, the probability spaces *are* the same because the resulting states are the same:

The state of the system $| \psi_1 \rangle$ after the measurement $M_1$ is,

$$ | \psi_1 \rangle = \frac{M_1 | \psi \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_1 | \psi \rangle}} .$$

Then, the state of the system $| \psi_2 \rangle$ after the measurement $M_2$ is,

$$ | \psi_2 \rangle = \frac{M_2 | \psi_1 \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi_1 | M_2^\dagger M_2 | \psi_1 \rangle}} $$

$$ \hspace{55mm}= \frac{M_2 M_1 | \psi \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_1 | \psi \rangle}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_1 | \psi \rangle}}{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_2^\dagger M_2 M_1 | \psi \rangle} $$

$$ \hspace{22mm} = \frac{M_2 M_1 | \psi \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_2^\dagger M_2 M_1 | \psi \rangle}} .$$

On the other hand, the state of the system $| \psi_3 \rangle $ after the measurement $ M_2 M_1 $ is,

$$ | \psi_3 \rangle = \frac{M_2 M_1 | \psi \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_2^\dagger M_2 M_1 | \psi \rangle}} = | \psi_2 \rangle .$$

Comment: Why do you think that the state after measuring $M_1$ on the state $\psi$ is $| \psi_1 \rangle = \frac{M_1 | \psi \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \psi | M_1^\dagger M_1 | \psi \rangle}} $ ?

Comment: It's the definition of the measurement operator, Nielson and Chuang Equation 2.93

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding with this formalism. If $M_i$ is a "measurement operator", then you don't "*measure $M_i$*", but rather you measure some underlying POVM, find an outcome $i$ with probability $\langle M_i\rangle_\psi$, and have a corresponding residual post-measurement state $\propto M_i |\psi\rangle$. So you "*find*" an outcome corresponding to $M_i$, more than "*perform the measurement $M_i$*". Thus, $\sim M_2 M_1|\psi\rangle$ is the state you get in the cases in which you found the outcomes $1$ and then $2$ (given some underlying, here unspecified, POVM)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't true. Here's a counterexample.

[image]

Note the density matrix after the product measurement is not the same as the density matrix after the two individual measurements.

Comment: I don't understand what question you answered.

Comment: The questions seems to be regarding measurement operators, not regarding measurement observables ~ for the operators, the cascaded measurement is actually equal to the (cartesian) product of the original operators.

Comment: The first words of the question clearly ask about measuring observables; and then OP uses formulas for measurement operators. I don't think that the question in its current form makes sense.

Comment: @kludg The wording of the question is kind of weird, I also don't know if it's a measurement operator or observable (but I guess it's the former) since we're asked to "Measure $AB$ on $|\psi\rangle$"

Comment: Looks like OP doesn't understand the difference between observables and  measurement operators.

Comment: @kludg The question is asking whether measuring one thing then another is the same as measuring their product. This is false, and I gave a counter-example. Another counter-example would show that e.g. measuring Z then measuring X on a qubit is not the same as measuring X*Z = iY. Not sure where the confusion is. I suppose you could take the interpretation of the question as "product means composition", but then it's just saying "is doing (A) then (B) the same as doing (A then B)" which seems trivial.

Comment: @CraigGidney I believe this is not what OP has asked. He was asking about *probability space*, and since observables $M_1$ and $M_2$ commute, there is no problems with probability space. You have shown that two different measurement procedures result in different states, yes, it should be so.